# Expected Time taken to transfer file from one node to another

Tags: linux

Time taken to sftp a file from one server to another is determined by many factors, i would like to know is there any way(in built function maybe) to estimate the time to be taken to transfer xGB of data using SFTP.

MY SFTP process is taking long time and i would want to determine the expected time of completion.

Comment: If you use `rsync`, it can show you a time estimation.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer would be "it all depends, your throughput I/O (network/storage)", but then again, you can always just try it out)

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=$$ bs=1024 count=1048576
1048576+0 records in
1048576+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 7.99025 s, 134 MB/s
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ time scp $$ alexus:.
10709                                                                            100% 1024MB 341.3MB/s   00:03    

real    0m3.431s
user    0m2.485s
sys 0m1.195s
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```